# sort by in Array ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have array

```
a = ["aaa", "bee", "cee", "dee"]
```

I want have new array with sort as like:

```
a = ["cee", "aaa", "dee", "bee"]
```

Please help me. thanks.

Comment: How exactly is this 'sorted' ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the order of your desired result.

Comment: What's the concrete logic of the desired sorting? Can you give another example? Or should the sorting (based on indices) consequently look like 2, 0, 3, 1 for arrays with length of 4?

Comment: I have video with 3 format: "Blueray,DVD, ipod". client need display video with sort as like: "DVD, Blueray, ipod". but 1 video can have 1, 2 or 3 format.

Comment: I suggest you to rephrase the question or it will be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = ["aaa", "bee", "cee", "dee"]
b = [a[2], a[0], a[3], a[1]]
```

Sorry, couldn't resist. Seriously, please explain this strange "sorting".

Answer (score 2):

you can give a block for the `Array.sort` method to have a custom sorting, like this:

```
[ "aaa", "bee", "cee", "dee"].sort do |x,y|
   # do the actual custom sorting
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at array intersection, e.g. `[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]`

The first of the two arrays determines the sorting of the elements. So, just use a predefined array `["DVD", "Blueray", "ipod"]` and perform an intersection operation with the unsorted array on it: `a = ["DVD", "Blueray", "ipod"] & a`.

For example: `a = ["DVD", "Blueray", "ipod"] & ["ipod", "DVD"]   #=> ["DVD", "ipod"]`.

Very elegant and simple solution. Bonus: Invalid values are discarded without any exception or error or what ever. (Is it a bonus? Maybe!)

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP needs, but i learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Going from your comments, you want to sort an array with names `Blueray,DVD, ipod` as `DVD, Bluray, ipod`.

An array is by definition order-based, unlike a hash. So if possible, you could just redefine your array in the correct order.

Otherwise i would suggest using a domain-table, with an id, name and description. Just make sure you insert the rows in the correct order (the id is the order), and all your select-boxes can use these options sorted as you want. Also using a domain-table you can then just refer to the video-type by id.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["aaa", "bee", "cee", "dee"]
a = [2, 0, 3, 1].map { |i| a[i] }
p a    # => ["cee", "aaa", "dee", "bee"]
```